# jquery-1.5.1.min.js and IE8

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery, jquery-validate

IE8 gives an error from jquery 1.5.1 minimized: `Invalid argument`, but firefox doesn't.

The error comes from this line:w

```
 a.elem.style&&a.elem.style[a.prop]!=null?a.elem.style[a.prop]=(a.prop==="width"||a.prop==="height"?Math.max(0,a.now):a.now)+a.unit:a.elem[a.prop]=a.now}}}),d.expr&&d.expr.filters&&(d.expr.filters.animated=function(a){return d.grep(d.timers,function(b){return a===b.elem}).length});var ce=/^t(?:able|d|h)$/i,cf=/^(?:body|html)$/i;"getBoundingClientRect"in c.documentElement?d.fn.offset=function(a){var b=this[0],c;if(a)return this.each(function(b){d.offset.setOffset(this,a,b)});if(!b||!b.ownerDocument)return null;if(b===b.ownerDocument.body)return d.offset.bodyOffset(b);try{c=b.getBoundingClientRect()}catch(e){}var f=b.ownerDocument,g=f.documentElement;if(!c||!d.contains(g,b))return c?{top:c.top,left:c.left}:{top:0,left:0};var h=f.body,i=cg(f),j=g.clientTop||h.clientTop||0,k=g.clientLeft||h.clientLeft||0,l=i.pageYOffset||d.support.boxModel&&g.scrollTop||h.scrollTop,m=i.pageXOffset||d.support.boxModel&&g.scrollLeft||h.scrollLeft,n=c.top+l-j,o=c.left+m-k;return{top:n,left:o}}:d.fn.offset=function(a){var b=this[0];if(a)return this.each(function(b){d.offset.setOffset(this,a,b)});if(!b||!b.ownerDocument)return null;if(b===b.ownerDocument.body)return d.offset.bodyOffset(b);d.offset.initialize();var c,e=b.offsetParent,f=b,g=b.ownerDocument,h=g.documentElement,i=g.body,j=g.defaultView,k=j?j.getComputedStyle(b,null):b.currentStyle,l=b.offsetTop,m=b.offsetLeft;while((b=b.parentNode)&&b!==i&&b!==h){if(d.offset.supportsFixedPosition&&k.position==="fixed")break;c=j?j.getComputedStyle(b,null):b.currentStyle,l-=b.scrollTop,m-=b.scrollLeft,b===e&&(l+=b.offsetTop,m+=b.offsetLeft,d.offset.doesNotAddBorder&&(!d.offset.doesAddBorderForTableAndCells||!ce.test(b.nodeName))&&(l+=parseFloat(c.borderTopWidth)||0,m+=parseFloat(c.borderLeftWidth)||0),f=e,e=b.offsetParent),d.offset.subtractsBorderForOverflowNotVisible&&c.overflow!=="visible"&&(l+=parseFloat(c.borderTopWidth)||0,m+=parseFloat(c.borderLeftWidth)||0),k=c}if(k.position==="relative"||k.position==="static")l+=i.offsetTop,m+=i.offsetLeft;d.offset.supportsFixedPosition&&k.position==="fixed"&&(l+=Math.max(h.scrollTop,i.scrollTop),m+=Math.max(h.scrollLeft,i.scrollLeft));return{top:l,left:m}},d.offset={initialize:function(){var a=c.body,b=c.createElement("div"),e,f,g,h,i=parseFloat(d.css(a,"marginTop"))||0,j="<div style='position:absolute;top:0;left:0;margin:0;border:5px solid #000;padding:0;width:1px;height:1px;'><div></div></div><table style='position:absolute;top:0;left:0;margin:0;border:5px solid #000;padding:0;width:1px;height:1px;' cellpadding='0' cellspacing='0'><tr><td></td></tr></table>";d.extend(b.style,{position:"absolute",top:0,left:0,margin:0,border:0,width:"1px",height:"1px",visibility:"hidden"}),b.innerHTML=j,a.insertBefore(b,a.firstChild),e=b.firstChild,f=e.firstChild,h=e.nextSibling.firstChild.firstChild,this.doesNotAddBorder=f.offsetTop!==5,this.doesAddBorderForTableAndCells=h.offsetTop===5,f.style.position="fixed",f.style.top="20px",this.supportsFixedPosition=f.offsetTop===20||f.offsetTop===15,f.style.position=f.style.top="",e.style.overflow="hidden",e.style.position="relative",this.subtractsBorderForOverflowNotVisible=f.offsetTop===-5,this.doesNotIncludeMarginInBodyOffset=a.offsetTop!==i,a.removeChild(b),a=b=e=f=g=h=null,d.offset.initialize=d.noop},bodyOffset:function(a){var b=a.offsetTop,c=a.offsetLeft;d.offset.initialize(),d.offset.doesNotIncludeMarginInBodyOffset&&(b+=parseFloat(d.css(a,"marginTop"))||0,c+=parseFloat(d.css(a,"marginLeft"))||0);return{top:b,left:c}},setOffset:function(a,b,c){var e=d.css(a,"position");e==="static"&&(a.style.position="relative");var f=d(a),g=f.offset(),h=d.css(a,"top"),i=d.css(a,"left"),j=e==="absolute"&&d.inArray("auto",[h,i])>-1,k={},l={},m,n;j&&(l=f.position()),m=j?l.top:parseInt(h,10)||0,n=j?l.left:parseInt(i,10)||0,d.isFunction(b)&&(b=b.call(a,c,g)),b.top!=null&&(k.top=b.top-g.top+m),b.left!=null&&(k.left=b.left-g.left+n),"using"in b?b.using.call(a,k):f.css(k)}},d.fn.extend({position:function(){if(!this[0])return null;var a=this[0],b=this.offsetParent(),c=this.offset(),e=cf.test(b[0].nodeName)?{top:0,left:0}:b.offset();c.top-=parseFloat(d.css(a,"marginTop"))||0,c.left-=parseFloat(d.css(a,"marginLeft"))||0,e.top+=parseFloat(d.css(b[0],"borderTopWidth"))||0,e.left+=parseFloat(d.css(b[0],"borderLeftWidth"))||0;return{top:c.top-e.top,left:c.left-e.left}},offsetParent:function(){return this.map(function(){var a=this.offsetParent||c.body;while(a&&(!cf.test(a.nodeName)&&d.css(a,"position")==="static"))a=a.offsetParent;return a})}}),d.each(["Left","Top"],function(a,c){var e="scroll"+c;d.fn[e]=function(c){var f=this[0],g;if(!f)return null;if(c!==b)return this.each(function(){g=cg(this),g?g.scrollTo(a?d(g).scrollLeft():c,a?c:d(g).scrollTop()):this[e]=c});g=cg(f);return g?"pageXOffset"in g?g[a?"pageYOffset":"pageXOffset"]:d.support.boxModel&&g.document.documentElement[e]||g.document.body[e]:f[e]}}),d.each(["Height","Width"],function(a,c){var e=c.toLowerCase();d.fn["inner"+c]=function(){return this[0]?parseFloat(d.css(this[0],e,"padding")):null},d.fn["outer"+c]=function(a){return this[0]?parseFloat(d.css(this[0],e,a?"margin":"border")):null},d.fn[e]=function(a){var f=this[0];if(!f)return a==null?null:this;if(d.isFunction(a))return this.each(function(b){var c=d(this);c[e](a.call(this,b,c[e]()))});if(d.isWindow(f)){var g=f.document.documentElement["client"+c];return f.document.compatMode==="CSS1Compat"&&g||f.document.body["client"+c]||g}if(f.nodeType===9)return Math.max(f.documentElement["client"+c],f.body["scroll"+c],f.documentElement["scroll"+c],f.body["offset"+c],f.documentElement["offset"+c]);if(a===b){var h=d.css(f,e),i=parseFloat(h);return d.isNaN(i)?h:i}return this.css(e,typeof a==="string"?a:a+"px")}}),a.jQuery=a.$=d})(window)
```

My code doesn't have an error...

Comment: Could you provide us an URL to check the bug ?

Comment: it's impossible to read all that code... just put the lines involved in the error...

Comment: Use the non-minified version and you'll have a **much** easier time figuring out what's going wrong.

Comment: @beginner Your code is causing the error (indirectly).

Comment: how can get error code show me invalid argument

Comment: @beginner Check the console, do an alert/console.log before certain code, etc.

Comment: @beginner Use "Developer Tools" (on IE8) or "Inspect element" on Chrome and you're going to detect the error in a few seconds using their Javascript debugger.

Comment: @Beginner: Help us to help you, and provide a clear/clean code.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest that you debug your code, as the min version of jquery works just fine. You have a problem with your code that is indirectly causing an error in internet explorer and you have to do a work around.

My favorite thing (and what I did for a similar problem that I just figured out) is to

1. cut out all your javascript and run it to make sure that it works
2. paste it back in, a chunk at a time, testing each time
3. once you find the offending chunk of javascript code, cut that out and put everything else back in to make sure that is the only problem
4. narrow it down in that chunk to see where internet explorer is being retarded. If you are using PHP, you might need to do something like this to have internet explorer skip the code that is causing it to fail

`$('li[title]').qtip({`

```
    style: { 
        name: 'dark',
        background: $('.ui-widget-header:first').css('background-color')
<?php   
//internet explorer is retarded
if(!preg_match('/MSIE/i',$_SERVER["HTTP_USER_AGENT"]))
{ 
        echo ", tip: true";
}   
?>
    },
    position: {
        target: 'mouse',
        corner: {
            target: 'topLeft',
            tooltip: 'bottomLeft'
        }
    }

});
```

I hope that helps! (If it did, please mark as answer)

Answer (score 1):

I used the "slideToggle" from jquery version "jquery-1.6.4.min.js" on one big DIV element.
The "DIV" element has inside more html elements.
In internet explorer 8 (maybe on FF too) when I try to load the slideToggle function on this big DIV I received an error. Not sure what was the real cause of error but during my investigation I found a bug into the jquery:

```
_default:function(a){a.elem.style&&a.elem.style[a.prop]!=null?a.elem.style[a.prop]=(a.prop==="width"||a.prop==="height"?Math.max(0,a.now):a.now)+a.unit:a.elem[a.prop]=a.now}}})
```

There are situations when "a" variable is "NAN". Because of this I got some errors.
So I placed this check routine inside:

```
if(isNaN(a.now)){return;}
```

And all my problems gone.

```
_default:function(a){if(isNaN(a.now)){return;}a.elem.style&&a.elem.style[a.prop]!=null?a.elem.style[a.prop]=(a.prop==="width"||a.prop==="height"?Math.max(0,a.now):a.now)+a.unit:a.elem[a.prop]=a.now}}})
```

Comment: It is true that this is a bug, but if you didn't wan't to modify the jQuery source code then you could explicitly setting the margin on your div. That worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

For me, this comes up when setting the padding or margins to a negative number. This has been discussed in a number of places online re: "IE negative padding". The following are the watch values from my IE console that prove this.

- a.prop >> 'paddingTop'
- a.prop==="width"||a.prop==="height" >> false
- Math.max(0,a.now) >> 0
- a.now >> -1.8277004484618357
- (a.prop==="width"||a.prop==="height"?Math.max(0,a.now):a.now)+a.unit >> "-1.8277004484618357px"

  - a.elem.style[a.prop]=(a.prop==="width"||a.prop==="height"?Math.max(0,a.now):a.now)+a.unit >> Invalid Argument

experimenting:
 - a.elem.style[a.prop] = '1px' >> '1px'
 - a.elem.style[a.prop] = '-1px' >> Invalid Argument

The thread over at: [StackOverflow: jQuery, IE & Animate](http://a.elem.style%5Ba.prop%5D=%28a.prop===%22width%22%7C%7Ca.prop===%22height%22?Math.max%280,a.now%7C%7C0%29%3aa.now%29%20a.unit;) proposes the following:

```
a.elem.style[a.prop]=(a.prop==="width"||a.prop==="height"?Math.max(0,a.now||0):a.now)+a.unit;
```

... which did nothing for me.

I don't really think this is a jQuery bug, and I haven't found it in their bug tracking system (I'll admit I haven't looked too hard), but rather an issue with IE not being able to handle negative padding/margins. It's a tough call whether jQuery should handle this or not ...

EDIT: This was opened as [jQuery bug 4571](http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/4571), where they decided that the behavior was correct and that developers should be more careful in setting margins/padding values since a negative margin/pad really isn't valid. They went on to say that they wish FF would throw an error like IE. Wow! don't hear that often!